# Stylus – Adding Percentages

Tags: css, percentage, addition, stylus

I'm having trouble with [Stylus](http://learnboost.github.com/stylus/). I'm simply trying to create a function which returns the width of a column given a span `n`. Here is my code:

```
column-gap = 1%
column-width = 15%

column-span(n)
(column-width * n) + (column-gap * (n - 1))
```

The problem is when `n` = 2 I'm expecting `column-span` to return `31%`, but it instead returns `30.3%`.

After some trial and error, I noticed that even this code complied to `30.3%`:

```
30% + 1%
```

I'm not sure what's going on here.

Comment: It isn't what I would have expected (Sass returns 31%), but 1% of 30 is `.3`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah, it's a bug in Stylus — it treats such input as if you're adding a percentage of the left part, so it adds the 1% of 30% to 30%.

You can use a workaround here like this:

```
column-span(n)
  (column-width * n) + unit(column-gap * (n - 1),"")
```

the thing you're doing here is removing the unit from the second part of the expression, so it would treat it as `30% + 1`, and in such cases Stylus would give you proper `31%`.